# Rails collection_check_boxes, Using two labels with one from an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an `Available` model with a date attribute, I also have a `User` model. A user `has_many :availables` and available `belongs_to :user`.

@dates is a collection of Available records. In the form I want to show both the date and the associated user name for that record. What I currently have is working though I can't click name to select the checkbox, is there a proper way to do this and style it via bootstrap?

```
    = f.collection_check_boxes :col_ids, @dates, :id, :date do |b|

      .field
        .checkbox-inline
           = b.check_box
           = b.label
           = b.object.user.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a checkbox which is inside the label tag.

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :col_ids, @dates, :id, :date do |b|
  .field
    .checkbox-inline
      = b.label do
        = b.check_box
        = b.text
        = b.object.user.name
```

On a side note your model should be named `Availablity` which is a noun. Not the adverb form *available* (*availables* is not an english word).

A person may be available, but has many availabilities.

> ### availability
>
> plural avail·abil·i·ties
>
> 1. the quality or state of being available
> 2. an available person or
>      thing
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/availability

This is not a big deal but can give english speakers are real WTF moment when trying to understand your code.

Comment: that just makes the date disappear and only shows the user name

Comment: Edited, when you pass a block to the label helper it overrides the content so you can put whatever you want inside.